# python pypi setup.py error (usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...])

Tags: python, pycharm, setup.py, pypi

when i try to run the setup.py file i get this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/user/PycharmProjects/quick_trade/quick_trade/setup.py
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied

Process finished with exit code 1
```

source: https://github.com/VvadKochetov007/quick_trade

Answer (score 1):

setup.py is a file that is executed by pip. Try going into the folder where setup.py is located, then run `pip install -e .`

Answer (score 1):

setup.py is not executed directly.In order to execute the file you first need to go the path where file is there:
cd/path

After run the below command in terminal:
If you want to use the package only:

```
python setup.py install
```

or
if you want to contribute:

```
python setup.py develop
```

These command help me to resolve the above error.

Answer (score -2):

hy, after :   python setup.py install

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Comment: This is very bad advice. `easy_install` should not be used anymore, it's deprecated for a reason. -- Whats is the point of this answer? Is this copy-pasted from a very old resource? Is this some more pseudo-AI-generated nonsense?